# How to deploy django app with apache and mod_wsgi so I can see the website when I type in server's address?

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy an existing django app that is running on my Ubuntu Server 14.04. Everything works on localhost from the server, but I have no idea how to link the server's IP address to the django app that I want. I have read countless tutorials and they fail in the sense of lack of information, which leaves me at this final step.

```
    # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
    # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
    # hints.
    #
    #
    # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
    # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
    # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
    # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
    # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
    # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
    # possible.

    # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
    # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
    #
    #   /etc/apache2/
    #   |-- apache2.conf
    #   |   `--  ports.conf
    #   |-- mods-enabled
    #   |   |-- *.load
    #   |   `-- *.conf
    #   |-- conf-enabled
    #   |   `-- *.conf
    #   `-- sites-enabled
    #       `-- *.conf
    #
    #
    # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
    #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
    #   web server.
    #
    # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
    #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
    #   customized anytime.
    #
    # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
    #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
    #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
    #   respectively.
    #
    #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
    #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
    #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
    #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
    #
    # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
    #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
    #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
    #   work with the default configuration.


    # Global configuration
    #

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
    # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
    # at );
    # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
    #
    # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
    ServerName localhost

    #
    # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
    #
    Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

    #
    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.
    # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    #
    PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

    #
    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 300

    #
    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive On

    #
    # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
    # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
    # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
    #
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    #
    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #
    KeepAliveTimeout 5


    # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

    #
    # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
    # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
    # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
    # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
    # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
    # nameserver.
    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a 
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a 
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
    # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
    #
    LogLevel warn

    # Include module configuration:
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

    # Include list of ports to listen on
    Include ports.conf

    # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
    # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
    # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
    # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
    # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
    # access here, or in any related virtual host.
    
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    

    
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    

    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    

    #
    #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #   AllowOverride None
    #   Require all granted
    #




    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
    # viewed by Web clients.
    #
    
        Require all denied
    


    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive.
    #
    # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
    # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
    # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
    # requests.
    #
    # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
    # Use mod_remoteip instead.
    #
    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
    # see README.Debian for details.

    # Include generic snippets of statements
    IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

    # Include the virtual host configurations:
    IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

    LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/sched_site/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/scheduler/sced_app:/home/user/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages

    
        
            Require all granted
        
    

    Alias /templates/admin/ /var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/templates/admin/

    
        Require all granted
    

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Error.log:

```
[Wed May 18 10:23:27.388123 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "/home/openflow/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.388132 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.388165 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "/home/openflow/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.388173 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397408 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397428 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397461 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "", line 2254, in _gcd_import
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397484 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397506 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397527 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397548 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "", line 2254, in _gcd_import
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397569 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397590 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711]   File "", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    [Wed May 18 10:23:27.397627 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244385715968] [remote 10.128.239.248:6711] ImportError: No module named 'sched_site'
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.604704 2016] [:error] [pid 11141:tid 140244492294016] Exception ignored in: 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.604704 2016] [:error] [pid 11140:tid 140244492294016] Exception ignored in: 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.604781 2016] [:error] [pid 11141:tid 140244492294016] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.604816 2016] [:error] [pid 11141:tid 140244492294016]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.604816 2016] [:error] [pid 11140:tid 140244492294016] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.604833 2016] [:error] [pid 11140:tid 140244492294016]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.621986 2016] [:error] [pid 11140:tid 140244492294016]     assert tlock is not None
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.621984 2016] [:error] [pid 11141:tid 140244492294016]     assert tlock is not None
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.622011 2016] [:error] [pid 11140:tid 140244492294016] AssertionError: 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.622019 2016] [:error] [pid 11141:tid 140244492294016] AssertionError: 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.664211 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 11136:tid 140244492294016] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.677625 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016] Exception ignored in: 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.677653 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.677671 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.678561 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016]     assert tlock is not None
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.678583 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016] AssertionError: 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.723109 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016] Exception ignored in: 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.723146 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.723160 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.723817 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016]     assert tlock is not None
    [Wed May 18 10:46:10.723836 2016] [:error] [pid 11139:tid 140244492294016] AssertionError: 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:11.656848 2016] [so:warn] [pid 11775:tid 140574671251328] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
    [Wed May 18 10:46:11.658535 2016] [:warn] [pid 11776:tid 140574671251328] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.0.
    [Wed May 18 10:46:11.658572 2016] [:warn] [pid 11776:tid 140574671251328] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.3.
    [Wed May 18 10:46:11.659664 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 11776:tid 140574671251328] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Wed May 18 10:46:11.659691 2016] [core:notice] [pid 11776:tid 140574671251328] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.527321 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735] mod_wsgi (pid=11779): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/scheduler.marist.edu/sched_app/sched_site/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.527422 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735] mod_wsgi (pid=11779): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/scheduler.marist.edu/sched_app/sched_site/wsgi.py'.
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.527483 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.527701 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "/var/www/html/scheduler.marist.edu/sched_app/sched_site/wsgi.py", line 16, in 
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.527713 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]     application = get_wsgi_application()
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.527845 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "/home/openflow/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.527870 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]     django.setup()
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528001 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "/home/openflow/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528012 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528182 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "/home/openflow/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528193 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]     self._setup(name)
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528232 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "/home/openflow/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528240 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528274 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "/home/openflow/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528282 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528442 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528453 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528478 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "", line 2254, in _gcd_import
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528501 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528524 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528546 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528568 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "", line 2254, in _gcd_import
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528589 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528611 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735]   File "", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    [Wed May 18 10:46:21.528642 2016] [:error] [pid 11779:tid 140574564673280] [remote 10.128.239.248:19735] ImportError: No module named 'sched_site'
```

Directory Structure:

```
app: /var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/sched_app
wsgi.py: /var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/sched_site
virtualenv: /~/.virtualenvs/sched_app.v0.1
```

Comment: could you post the code of Apache conf file? and Apache error log would be also helpful.

Comment: your django wsgi file needs to be pointed to by your apache virtualhost file in your sites_enabled and sites_available folders.  Your server uses these files to figure out which application folder to hit

Comment: Check the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: First of all, thanks for the speedy response The wsgi file I believe is pointed, I am not sure though. @Anoop I went through the tutorial and I get a '404 error' when I type in the IP address of the server in my browser

Comment: Youcompleted all the steps and getting a 404 error now?
Can you check the apache error log?

Comment: I am getting a '500 internal error', the error says 'Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as a python module' and then 'Exception occurred processing WSGI script' and later at the end there is a python error 'ImportError: No module named 'sched_site' (which is the name of my django directory with settings.py and so forth). @Anoop

Comment: Can you post the directory structure and error log

Comment: I posted some directory structures, and a good portion of the error.log. Unfortunately, I can't post the whole error.log because it's too large. Thanks for the help @Anoop by the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284814/django-apache-configuration-with-wsgidaemonprocess-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to wsgi.py file and try.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app')
```

Comment: Yeah I linked it to the directory where the wsgi.py file resides, and still nothing

Comment: No, Your project root directory is '/var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app' and wsgi.py is in '/var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/sched_app', rightr? 
So you should add the above line on the top of wsgi.py file.
restart apache and please check..

Comment: My wsgi.py file resides in "/var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/sched_site/", so I should put "/var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/" in the WSGI file?

Comment: I think so, if "/var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/" is your project root.
Don't forget to restart apache after any changes

Comment: So theres the project root and the app root, in django there can be multiple apps in one project, therefore, under "/var/www/html/scheduler/sched_app/" I have two directories "sched_app" which contains the views and models and "sched_site" which contains the settings and wsgi.py file, should I set it outside of both of these, or in the "sched_site" folder? just to be clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this guide:

```
yum check-update 
yum groupinstall -y "Development tools"
----------------------------------------------------------------
Apache2.4
----------------------------------------------------------------
yum install -y httpd httpd-devel
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload

chgrp -R apache /var/www/html
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+rx {} +
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod g+r {} +

chown -R myuser /var/www/html/
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod u+rwx {} +
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod u+rw {} +

find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +

----------------------------------------------------------------
MySQL
----------------------------------------------------------------
yum install -y mariadb-server mariadb
systemctl start mariadb.service
systemctl enable mariadb.service
mysql_secure_installation
----------------------------------------------------------------
php, phpmyadmin along with other dependencies
----------------------------------------------------------------
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms

yum install -y php php-mysql php-gd php-pear php-mbstring php-pgsql phpmyadmin
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
Add IP in conf.
systemctl restart httpd.service
----------------------------------------------------------------
Python3.5 along with lib and devel packages
----------------------------------------------------------------
yum install -y https://rhel7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
yum install -y python35u python35u-libs python35u-devel python35u-pip
pip3.5 install virtualenv
----------------------------------------------------------------
mod-wsgi
----------------------------------------------------------------
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.5.14.tar.gz
tar -zxvf 4.5.14.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-4.5.14
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.5
make
make install
chmod 755 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
----------------------------------------------------------------
myportal.conf
----------------------------------------------------------------
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/myportal.conf

LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@email.com
  ServerName myportal
  ServerAlias myportal.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myportal/src/

  WSGIDaemonProcess myportal python-path=/var/www/html/myportal/src:/var/www/html/myportal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
  WSGIApplicationGroup myportal
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myportal/src/myportal/wsgi.py process-group=myportal

  <Directory /var/www/html/myportal/src>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/myportal/src/myportal>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Apache configuration has issues as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/43192744/128141