# django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, wsgi

**Updated Question**

```
[Mon Jul 18 09:20:10.517873 2016] [:error] [pid 30316:tid 139756302964480] [remote 122.164.94.99:48261] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 18 09:20:10.518005 2016] [:error] [pid 30316:tid 139756302964480] [remote 122.164.94.99:48261]   File "/var/www/rent/Rent/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
[Mon Jul 18 09:20:10.518141 2016] [:error] [pid 30316:tid 139756302964480] [remote 122.164.94.99:48261]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Jul 18 09:20:10.518236 2016] [:error] [pid 30316:tid 139756302964480] [remote 122.164.94.99:48261] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

**My virtualhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  ip_address
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    Alias /static/  /var/www/rent/static/

    Alias /media/  /var/www/rent/media/

    WSGIScriptAlias /   /var/www/rent/Rent/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess   Rent  python-path=/var/www/rent:/root/.virtualenvs/rent/lib/python2.7/site-packages

    WSGIProcessGroup    Rent

    <Directory /var/www/rent/static>
        Options -Indexes
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/rent/media>
        Options -Indexes
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog    ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How is it "not working as expected"? Can you include some logs and error messages in your question?

Comment: @GarrettHyde Whatever modules I have installed in virtualenv it is showing as module not found

Comment: @GarrettHyde Added the log

Comment: Did you read the exception message in the log and check the value of `TEMPLATE_DIRS`? If the value is such that you should not get the error you are getting, are you sure that the server is pointing your Django application to the right settings? If you temporarily add `raise Exception("Let's see.")` at the start of your `settings.py` and try accessing your site again, does the exception show up in the logs?

Comment: @Louis I check it and I have added `,` hence the above issue resolved and then throwing exceptions as `some module`(Installed) module not found

Comment: So it sounds like your question has been answered.  If it's still not working, can you please update the question to cover your new symptoms?

Comment: @e4c5 let make it simple, here is the url http://139.162.167.86/ and updated the question with new error message

Comment: @e4c5 I am using virtualenv for the configuration, I can also post the virtualhost

Comment: @e4c5 the second one is the newly updated one

Comment: They look so very different and confusing to someone trying to help. Can yo please update the question and trim off the old stuff. Leave only the present configuration and related stuff

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
WSGIDaemonProcess   Rent  python-path=/var/www/rent:/root/.virtualenvs/rent/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This is the most likely cause of the problem. You have created a virtualenv inside the super user's home folder. But that folder is unlikely to be accessible to apache. A user's home folder is not accessible to any other user by default.

The web server and the WSGI process will be running as a non privileged user typically named `nobody`, `httpd`, `apache` or something similar. While you can fix this problem by changing the permissions on /root/ that's a big no no. It would be less dangerous if it was an ordinary user but still not a good idea to do this.

The best solution is to put the virtualenv in a location accessible by the unprivileged user.  `/usr/local/virtualenv` is a good location.

Please note that moving `/root/.virtualenvs/` to `/usr/local/virtualenv` you will have to recreate it as follows

```
 source /root/.virtualenvs/rent/bin/activate
 pip freeze > /tmp/requirements.txt
 cd /usr/local/
 virtualenv virtualenv
 source virtualenv/bin/activate
 pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

then edit the `httpd.conf` file to reflect the new path.

Comment: Using ``python-path`` to set up a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi daemon mode is not the recommended method. Use ``python-home`` instead as explained in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: thanks @GrahamDumpleton will look that up and update the answer

Comment: I was going crazy, I had the same problem and I checked the paths thousands of times, here the solution! ty

Comment: THANKYOU! I was following the digitalocean page, and had multiple virtual environments, one for a staging site and the other for production site. You can imagine the confusion when testing a Django upgrade. +1 from me, but should be +1000