# Deploying Django on Apache2 with mod_wsgi - Correct location for Django project?

Tags: django, apache, deployment, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my first Django project on my webserver. I am both new to server configuration and Django so I have a hard time finding my errors.

In most tutorials I have seen online, the Django project on the production server is created in /var/www/myproject - however, the Django documentation recommends putting the code outside of /var/www/ for security reasons (see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/).

So, I put my Django project in a subdirectory of my home folder, which is not accessible to Apache. I added no file to /var/www as no tutorial mentions that this would be necessary.

After setting up Django with mod_wsgi according to these tutorials:
 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ ,
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04 ,
http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/)
when I access my webserver via browser all I see is the default index.html site.
Running and accessing the development server of Django from my webserver does not work either. In both cases, when I try to access the admin page I get a standard 404 Error.

Am I supposed to put some files into /var/www/ after all?

Could it be an issue that I use a Let'sEncrypt certificate and during the setup with auto-certbot chose to automatically redirect http to https?

Some of my configured files (I left out parts that I didn't change/have nothing to do with Django):

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /static /home/me/django/mysite/app/static
    <Directory /home/me/django/mysite/app/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/me/django/mysite/mysite>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/home/me/django/mysite:/home/me/django/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

**/home/me/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/sirhys/django/mysite'  
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

**/home/me/django/mysite/mysite/settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
        'www.mysite.com',
        'mysite.com'
]

SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'app/static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Thank you!

Edit:
In the end, I found the issue to be a conflict between the different out-of-the-box config files I have on my server. Apparently, the Let's Encrypt SSL config file was overriding all other files in /etc/apache2/sites-available. When I put the WSGI-config lines there, it worked like a charm.
I have my code in my home directory now, and it is working. I decided to put my static files into /var/www/static via `collectstatic`. This is working for me but it seems the exact location of code and static files is really irrelevant.

Comment: Is that .conf file symlinked to sites-enabled? Have you reloaded Apache?

Comment: It's not symlinked. Which conf file should I symlink? apache2 or default? And how would I do that? I have reloaded Apache though.

Comment: 000-default.conf. Apache won't use it unless it's actually in the sites-enabled folder. You can run `sudo a2ensite 000-default` to do it automatically.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman! I did it, but got a  `Site 000-default already enabled` - so that wasn't it.

Comment: Is that all you have in ``000-default.conf``? You seemed to have removed various stuff that would normally be present.

Comment: It's not the full `000-default.conf` - I left out the `ServerAdmin`, `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` specifications as I didn't think them important here. What is missing? Also, I have other conf files out of the box: `mysite.com.conf`, `mysite.com-le-ssl.conf`, `deafault-ssl.conf` which are all in sites-available, too. And then there is a separate `apache2.conf` in /etc/apache2. I did not create any of those by hand and only modified `apache2.conf` and `000-default.conf` if I recall correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284814/django-apache-configuration-with-wsgidaemonprocess-not-working)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your config only for one website, need use virtual host

Example deploy:

For python3 install mod_wsgi (debian based system)

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Put your project in standard apache location

```
/var/www/myproj
```

where myproj = name you django project

Check project

```
python3 manage.py check
```

or/and run it

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

if your domain example.com, then http://example.com:8000/ or use server IP.

Allow apache2 read and write content

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/myproj -R
```

Config apache 2.4

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
editor myproj.conf
```

and Apache2.4 minimal config (many sites)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/myproj

WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www/myproj

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproj/myproj/wsgi.py \
    process-group=example.com application-group=%{GLOBAL}

<Directory /var/www/myproj/myproj>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

# static
Alias /media/ /var/www/myproj/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/myproj/static/
Alias /robots.txt /var/www/myproj/robots.txt
# logs
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myproj-error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myproj-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Virtualenv: python path + virtual, example

```
python-path=/path/www/myproj python-home=/path/to/venv
```

Using daemon mode exclusively, add to /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
```

Enable config

```
a2ensite myproj.conf
```

Check syntax

```
apachectl -t
```

Restart apache or reload

```
service apache2 restart
```

---

Example config apache2.4 with define variable. Django > 1.6. Set only domain, path, name project. 
In example path to dir /var/www/example.com/myproject/myproect/wsgi.py, static url /media/ and /static/

Define:

1. domain - your domain name (example.com)
2. path - full path to project, folder where manage.py (/var/www/example.com/myproj)
3. project - name project, folder name where wsgi.py (myproj)

https://gist.github.com/leotop/9a78c10c0961cdd2bbe9633d6ebf8a5b

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Define domain example.com
Define path /var/www/${domain}/myproj
Define project myproj


ServerName ${domain}
ServerAlias www.${domain}

DocumentRoot ${path}

WSGIDaemonProcess ${domain} python-path=${path}

WSGIScriptAlias / ${path}/${project}/wsgi.py \
    process-group=${domain} application-group=%{GLOBAL}

<Directory ${path}/${project}>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


Alias /media/ ${path}/media/
Alias /static/ ${path}/static/
Alias /robots.txt ${path}/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico ${path}/static/favicon.ico

<Location "/media/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>

<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/${domain}-error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/${domain}-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for this concise and detailed tutorial! I am going to uninstall everything and start over from scratch. One more question: You put the entire code into /var/www/ - doesn't this make the code accessible through the browser? The [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) advises against putting code there so I'm somewhat confused since a lot of people put it into /var/www/ despite that.

Comment: /var/www/ - standard path for website on server. Apache 2 allow access only for /var/www and /var/log. /home/ - user data, password, bank ...

Comment: default host apache 2.4 /var/www/html/ not access for /var/www/project.
apache 2.2 - default host /var/www/ allow access for /var/www/project ... http://0.0.0.0/project/

Comment: Develop - in home dir, deploy - only dir where apache allow access or use run user, run group.

Comment: Production. Enable apache mods: status, deflate, ... and add to section virtualhost https://gist.github.com/leotop/1e30214a89eb39720c9b7461c572dbcd

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I am currently trying this. I copied my project folder from my home directory to /var/www/ - running `python manage.py check` (I am using Python2.7) shows no issues. But I still cannot access the development server from the browser.

Comment: develop server run on port >80 and IP 0.0.0.0

Comment: if your VDS/Dedicatet server ip 88.11.22.33, then run django on port 8000 (command python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000). View http://88.11.22.33:8000

Comment: Yes, that is what I have been doing. All the browser does is load endlessly. On the terminal I don't get any output at all, so I think the GET requests from my browser just never reach django.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117487/discussion-between-igor-and-hsvar).

Comment: Using ``<Directory />`` which includes ``Require all granted`` is bad practice as it means Apache can serve up any file from your whole computer. Should only be done for directory ``/var/www/myproj/myproj`` and file ``wsgi.py`` within it so that WSGI application will load. All the static files should be pushed down one directory and then access granted to just those static files.

Comment: Thanks. %{GLOBAL} The application group name will be set to the empty string.

Any WSGI applications in the global application group will always be executed within the context of the first interpreter created by Python when it is initialised. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIApplicationGroup.html
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/11/save-on-memory-with-modwsgi-30.html

Comment: Fix. Add to answer. Change Require all granted to wsgi.py. Example conf with define variable.

Comment: This is a great answer. How do you set it up if your static files are served by a separate virtual host? I have mine setup that way, working find with DEBUG = True, but when I set DEBUG = False, the site throws 500 errors. So I don't have Alias /media and Alias /static in my vhost.