# How to uninstall mod_wsgi when installed with make?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, uninstallation

I have installed mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 14.04 as described in their [documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html). While I don't get any errors from Apache or anything my Django setup does not work (no idea why exactly) so I would like to start over and use libapache2-mod-wsgi.

However, I don't know how to uninstall mod_wsgi. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1439989/6488418) answer to a more general question on the subject advises trying `make uninstall` which does not work in this case.

`make -n install` gives me the following output:

```
/usr/bin/apxs2 -c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -Wc,-g -Wc,-O2  src/server/mod_wsgi.c src/server/wsgi_*.c -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config  -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/usr/bin/apxs2 -i -S LIBEXECDIR=/usr/lib/apache2/modules -n 'mod_wsgi' src/server/mod_wsgi.la
```

What exactly do I have to do to uninstall this?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using mod_wsgi-4.5.3.

Answer (score 9):

Remove any configuration you added to Apache configuration files and also run:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

I would strongly recommend against using the system provided mod_wsgi package as it is generally out of date by many many versions and is also thus not supported. You are better off using the latest from source code and trying to work out what the problem is, exact details of which you haven't posted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the recommendation! I have described my problem in a different question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383407/deploying-django-on-apache2-with-mod-wsgi-correct-location-for-django-project) - perhaps you could take a look.