# Can't run Apache2 with virtualenv

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I'm making a website based on Django, on the server was installed a Python 3.5, but my project requires a Python 3.6. I decided to use virtualenv. I successfuly installed needed version of Python but I can't make it works with Apatche2 using `virtualenv`.

Website is able to run only on Python 2.7, otherwise nothing happens, page is loading for a long time without any error.

Here is my VirtualHost config with my try to run on Python 3.6.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName <site_adress>:443
    ServerAdmin admin@<site_adress>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MMServer

    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mm.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mm.key

    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/MMServer/static/

    <Directory /var/www/html/MMServer/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess MMServer python-path=/var/www/html/MMServer python-home=/var/www/html/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup MMServer
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/MMServer/mm_server/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/html/MMServer/mm_server>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Below is my `wsgi.py` file:

```py
import os
import sys

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK',[('Content-type','text/html')])
    return [sys.version]
```

Only one thing what I can get this way (while `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIProcessGroup` is deleted) is:

> 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]

### Edit 1:

There is a posiblity I have missing packages, bacause I made reinstalation of python 3.5, what are required packages to work?

## Solution:

I did two things, I'm not sure what exacly help me but first of all I disabled a mod (`a2dismod wsgi`) and deleted a package `libapache2-mod-wsgi`.

#### Option 1:

`apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

#### Option 2:

I installed a `mod-wsgi` from the source:
`wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.6.3.tar.gz`
`tar -xf 4.6.3.tar.gz`
`./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.6`
`make`
`make install`
Now everything works perfectly.
Thanks @Graham Dumpleton, your answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. This worked for me. This needs to be documented on the official Django website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod_wsgi module is C code which links to the Python library. Thus the version of Python it is compiled for is embedded in the module. It doesn't just execute `python` program. This means it has to be compiled for the version of Python you want to use. You cannot force it via a virtual environment to use a different Python version. This is stated in the documentation on using mod_wsgi with virtual environments.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

In short, you need to uninstall the mod_wsgi module (likely the operating system packaged one), and install mod_wsgi yourself from source code, compiling it against the Python version you want to use. Easiest way of doing that is to use `pip install` method.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi