# Multiple Sites with Django, Virtualenv, and WSGI on Apache

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, wsgi

The goal is to run Django in daemon mode on Apache via WSGI. I plan to run it on port 8000 to keep it separate from PHP files running at the root of server's URL (unless there's a better way to keep my web applications separate). It's setup with Virtualenv.

Server is named server.family.local

The simplified file structure is:

```
/home
    /wwww
        /django
            /my_project
                /app1
                /app2
                /project
                    wsgi.py
            /env
                /lib
                    /python3.5
                        /site-packages
```

The system runs properly when I activate the Virtualenv and use the manage.py file:

```
/home/www/django/my_project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I'm trying to setup the WSGI on Apache so I don't have to manually run that command every time. My wsgi.py file consists of this:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/home/www/django/my_project')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The VirtualHost file for Apache, server_django.conf, has this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py
    WSGIProcessGroup my_project
    WSGIDaemonProcess my_project python-path=/home/www/django/my_project/vision:/home/www/django/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages

    Alias /static /home/www/django/my_project/project/static
    <Directory /home/www/django/my_project/project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/www/django/my_project/project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've enabled the site using a2ensite. I checked that I have only libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 installed (not libpache2-mod-python or libpache2-mod-wsgi). I think permissions are safe. Owner is my name but group is www, which is what Apache uses. The virtualenv directory has the same owner, group, and 775 permissions tag. The Python version could be an issue but I don't think it should be. When I'm in the virtualenv and run python -V, I get Python 3.5.1+. Outside the virtualenv, I get Python 2.7.12. My understanding is that this is why we use virtualenv - to isolate versions. So, if the Apache Virtual Host and the wsgi.py files are configured correctly, this shouldn't be the problem (I think).

When I try to reach my site at http://server.family.local:8000 I get a 500 Internal Server Error and find the following statements in the Apache error log.

```
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:05.850055 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] mod_wsgi (pid=1003): Target WSGI script '/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:05.850199 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] mod_wsgi (pid=1003): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:05.850645 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:05.850721 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382]   File "/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:05.850735 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:05.850787 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.062315 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] mod_wsgi (pid=1003): Target WSGI script '/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.062405 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] mod_wsgi (pid=1003): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.062573 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.062625 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382]   File "/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.062637 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.062684 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.467512 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] mod_wsgi (pid=1003): Target WSGI script '/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.467594 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] mod_wsgi (pid=1003): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.467757 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.467809 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382]   File "/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.467822 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.467868 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.658228 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] mod_wsgi (pid=1003): Target WSGI script '/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.658312 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] mod_wsgi (pid=1003): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.658476 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.658527 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382]   File "/home/www/django/my_project/project/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.658540 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Jul 27 22:56:06.658587 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 1003] [remote 192.168.14.185:3382] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I'm not an expert but seems that the problem starts with it's unable to load the wsgi.py file but I can't see why that would be any problem. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Take a note that you need to make sure that wsgi is compiled for the same python version that you run the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284814/django-apache-configuration-with-wsgidaemonprocess-not-working)

Comment: I think permissions are safe. Owner is my name but group is www, which is what Apache uses. The virtualenv directory has the same owner, group, and 775 permissions tag.

The Python version could be an issue but I don't think it should be. When I'm in the virtualenv and run `python -V`, I get Python 3.5.1+. Outside the virtualenv, I get Python 2.7.12. My understanding is that this is why we use virtualenv - to isolate versions. So, if the Apache Virtual Host and the wsgi.py files are configured correctly, this shouldn't be the problem (I think).

Comment: you would need to make even your home folder group readable which it usually is not

Comment: The /home/ directory is the two levels up. If everything is being served under /home/www/django - including the virtualenv - it seems only the /home/www/django would need to be readable.
As it is, /home is globally readable.as is /home/www.