# Python 3.5 and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I use Python 3.5 with virtualenv, and I'm trying connect it with mod_wsgi

```
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/myapp/my_app/my_app/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myapp/my_app/my_app/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Apache config:

```
...
DocumentRoot /home/myapp/my_app/
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myapp/my_app/my_app/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess python-path=/home/myapp/my_app/:/home/myapp/myapp_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages:/home/myapp

<Directory /home/myapp/my_app/ad_server>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
<Location "/">
   Require all granted
</Location>
Alias /static /home/myapp/my_app/static
...
```

And wsgi

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284814/django-apache-configuration-with-wsgidaemonprocess-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the process group name for `WSGIDaemonProcess` and also missing a corresponding `WSGIProcessGroup` directive or `process-group` option to `WSGIScriptAlias`. So even if had the process group name, the WSGI application would not be run in the daemon process group and so doesn't know about the virtual environment.

Use:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess my_app python-home=/home/myapp/myapp_venv python-path=/home/myapp/my_app
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myapp/my_app/my_app/wsgi.py process-group=my_app application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

The directives need to be in that order, so make sure `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive comes first when using `process-group` option to `WSGIScriptAlias`.