# Setting up Apache2 to use Django with mod_wsgi, No module named 'django' error

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2

I am trying to set up Apache2 to use mod_wsgi to connect to Django.

I have a local development server set up running apache2 to serve the majority of the files for the website. However, I wish to serve the contact page using Django as I have a Django app that is a contact form.

I am also using virtualenv as the python path.

I have followed the instructions on the Django project documentation.

My folder structure is:

```
-mysite.com

    -myproject

        -contactApp

        -myproject

        -env
```

**mysite.com.conf**

```
<Directory /home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com python-home=/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/env python-path=/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com
WSGIScriptAlias /contact /home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py process-group=mysite.com
```

The problem that I am having is a 500 Internal Server error when I try to reach mysite.com/contact

The apache error.log gives the following errors:

```
[Mon Jun 12 23:03:09.649249 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 25755:tid 139706287081216['/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/env/lib/python35.zip', '/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/env/lib/python3.5', '/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/env/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/env/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
[Mon Jun 12 23:03:09.649846 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 25755:tid 139706287081216] [remote 127.0.0.1:39990] mod_wsgi (pid=25755): Target WSGI script '/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Jun 12 23:03:09.649925 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 25755:tid 139706287081216] [remote 127.0.0.1:39990] mod_wsgi (pid=25755): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jun 12 23:03:09.650380 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 25755:tid 139706287081216] [remote 127.0.0.1:39990] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jun 12 23:03:09.650450 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 25755:tid 139706287081216] [remote 127.0.0.1:39990]   File "/home/user/Documents/webdev/mysite.com/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[Mon Jun 12 23:03:09.650462 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 25755:tid 139706287081216] [remote 127.0.0.1:39990]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Jun 12 23:03:09.650512 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 25755:tid 139706287081216] [remote 127.0.0.1:39990] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

To check if it was an error with my virtualenv I tried importing django using the virtualenv and that imports fine.

My wsgi.py file is the one automatically generated when starting a new django project, i.e.

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Can anyone help me diagnose the problem as I have tried searching for a solution but none have helped? Thanks.

Comment: You should not need the ``python-path`` option as ``python-home`` set to value of ``sys.prefix`` for the Python virtual environment should be enough. The issue though is whether your mod_wsgi was even compiled for Python 3.5 installation that your virtual environment was created from. Also, your code will run as a special Apache user by default. Does that user have read access to ``/home/user`` and all directories/files down to where your project and virtual environment is.

Comment: Relevant links http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html and http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I tried the exact import that was causing the error within a python shell within the virtualenv. Does this indicate that mod_wgsi is compiled for my virtualenv installation? As a desperate measure and because it's only a local dev environment any user can access the files needed.

Comment: But you are doing that import as you and not likely the user Apache runs your code as. The Apache user may not be able to read into the directories if permissions of directories/files are too restrictive.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thank you for the links. I will have a look tomorrow (it's pretty late here!)

Comment: Try setting ``user=xx`` and ``group=yy`` options on ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` directive to match your user name (xx) and group name (yy). That is one way around permissions issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django apache configuration with WSGIDaemonProcess not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284814/django-apache-configuration-with-wsgidaemonprocess-not-working)

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I ended up following a digital ocean tutorial and starting from scratch. I noticed that when I was activating my virtualenv and installing django it was installing outside of my virtualenv for some reason. I also put my virtualenv directory outside my user directory. It is all working now, thanks for your help.